# How to filter Sonar results by plugin

Tags: sonarqube

I want to filter the results to show only bugs found by Findbugs plugins. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible. If you want to have only Findbugs violations, then you can create a quality profile with only Findbugs rules.